# Why won't Git let me check out a branch from an alternate remote?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-remote

I'm working on a project that has two remotes, one called `origin` and one called `vsts`. The default remote is `origin`. Here's the output from `git remote -v`, with some parts anonymized as `***`:

`$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:***/***.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:***/***.git (push)
vsts    ssh://***@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:***/DefaultCollection/***/_ssh/*** (fetch)
vsts    ssh://***@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:***/DefaultCollection/***/_ssh/*** (push)`

I'm trying to check out a new branch from `vsts`. It's called `release/1.4.1`. I'm on Git 2.16.x, so I should be able to use `git checkout`, but this is what happens:

`$ git checkout release/1.4.1
error: pathspec 'release/1.4.1' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

I think maybe it's assuming I meant `origin`. So I try this:

`$ git checkout vsts/release/1.4.1
error: pathspec 'vsts/release/1.4.1' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

I should make sure git can find the branch. So I use `git ls-remote` to get a list of remote branches:

`$ git ls-remote vsts
...
abcde***   refs/heads/release/1.4.1
...`

I get a list of branches and commit hashes, and `release/1.4.1` is definitely one of them.

I try a few more things:

`$ git checkout -b release/1.4.1 vsts/release/1.4.1
fatal: 'vsts/release/1.4.1' is not a commit and a branch 'release/1.4.1' cannot be created from it`

`$ git fetch vsts release/1.4.1
From ssh://vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:***/DefaultCollection/***/_ssh/***
 * branch                release/1.4.1 -> FETCH_HEAD`

(After this command, I try all the previous ones again. The results are unchanged.)

`$ git checkout -b release/1.4.1 remotes/vsts/release/1.4.1
fatal: 'remotes/vsts/release/1.4.1' is not a commit and a branch 'release/1.4.1' cannot be created from it`

`$ git checkout -b release/1.4.1 remotes/vsts/refs/heads/release/1.4.1
fatal: 'remotes/vsts/refs/heads/release/1.4.1' is not a commit and a branch 'release/1.4.1' cannot be created from it`

If I try `git pull vsts/release/1.4.1` it successfully merges the remote branch `release/1.4.1` into the current branch, but that's not a useful workaround here.

What else can I try? I don't understand why I can't check out the remote branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that my local git config was messed up. I used `git config --local -e` to open it in vim and found this section:

`[remote "vsts"]
  url = ssh://***@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:***/DefaultCollection/***/_ssh/***
  fetch = +refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/vsts/dev`

Which looks like it's only set up to fetch `dev`. I don't know how it got that way, but I changed it to the following:

`[remote "vsts"]
  url = ssh://***@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:***/DefaultCollection/***/_ssh/***
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/vsts/*`

After which I'm able to do this:

`$ git checkout release/1.4.1
Switched to a new branch 'release/1.4.1'
Branch 'release/1.4.1' set up to track remote branch 'release/1.4.1' from 'vsts'.`

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it got that way either, but that's the right fix. Note that `git remote add`, which adds an additional remote, allows `-t <branch>` to limit the fetching to one specific branch. It does this by writing the `fetch =` refspec as you saw.